# Flip entire animation

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, mirror, 2d

I'm trying to mirror this entire animation sequence which I made in Blender's 2D Animation preset workspace. When I try to, I get an animation of the sequence mirroring around an axis. How do I mirror the entire thing? (Not including the background image).

[image]

Comment: did you try s x -1 ?

Comment: Or what you show in your screenshot? It should do the trick just fine.

Comment: Even if I select all of the keyframes, it only mirrors the first one, and the rest animate the object turning back to its original state around the Z axis, if that makes any sense.

Comment: mirror should work, or like Chris said or rotating 180 degrees on the z axis, but in any case you want to disable auto-keyframing when doing it